# Expected Method ShortHand EsLint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

When I used `onClick` function as mentioned below EsLint error occurs   Expected method shorthand  object-shorthand.

```
onClick: function (c, i) {
  e = i[0]
  console.log(e._index)
  const x_value = this.data.labels[e._index]
  const y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index]
  console.log(x_value)
  console.log(y_value)
}
```

Comment: `onClick(c, i) {}`

Comment: See [the first result if you search for this](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-shorthand), the official eslint page on this rule